# SQL - String concatenated grouping WITHOUT DISTINCT

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm wondering if this is possible - I have a table like this:

```
pk int, num int, name varchar(1)
1       1        'a'
2       1        'b'
3       1        'c'
4       1        'd'
5       1        'e'
6       2        'f'
7       2        'g'
8       2        'h'
9       2        'i'
10      2        'j'
```

And I'd like an output like this WITHOUT using a DISTINCT clause:

```
num  result
1    a,b,c,d,e
2    f,g,h,i,j
```

Here are ddl statements for testing:

```
declare @tbl table (pk int, num int, name varchar(1))
insert into @tbl select 1, 1, 'a'
insert into @tbl select 2, 1, 'b'
insert into @tbl select 3, 1, 'c'
insert into @tbl select 4, 1, 'd'
insert into @tbl select 5, 1, 'e'
insert into @tbl select 6, 2, 'f'
insert into @tbl select 7, 2, 'g'
insert into @tbl select 8, 2, 'h'
insert into @tbl select 9, 2, 'i'
insert into @tbl select 10, 2, 'j'
```

The following query works, but I'd like to eliminate the DISTINCT clause if possible:

```
select DISTINCT num, stuff((select ',' + name from @tbl where num = t.num for xml path('')), 1, 1, '')
from @tbl t
```

Any idea how to do this in SQL 2012+?

Comment: You can wrap the query in a cte and then select from it with group by on both columns, however that is a longer, more complicated code that will probably not give you any benefit at all.

Comment: Why do you want to remove the distinct clause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have a list of `num` values that you want, then you can create one.  One rather silly way is:

```
select t.num,
       stuff( (select ',' + name
               from @tbl t2
               where t2.num = t.num
               for xml path('')
              ), 1, 1, '')
from (values (1), (2)) as t(num);
```

More commonly, this would be written as:

```
select t.num,
       stuff( (select ',' + name
               from @tbl t2
               where t2.num = t.num
               for xml path('')
              ), 1, 1, '')
from (select distinct num from @tbl) t;
```

Comment: Thanks - just what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

Try this I think it will work fine

```
select num, group_concat(name) from table_name group by num;
```

Comment: Thanks for a MySQL approach - but this is sql server!